# Theoretically, can everyday computing tasks be broken down into ones solvable by a neural network?

Tags: neural-network

MIT Review recently published this article about a chip from IBM, which is more or less a Artificial neural network. [Why IBM’s New Brainlike Chip May Be “Historic” | MIT Technology Review](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/529691/ibm-chip-processes-data-similar-to-the-way-your-brain-does/?utm_campaign=socialsync&utm_medium=social-post&utm_source=facebook)

The article suggests that the chip might have borrowed a page from the future. It might be the beginning of an era of new and evolved computation power. And also talks about programming for the chip.

> One downside is that IBM’s chip requires an entirely new approach to
>   programming. Although the company announced a suite of tools geared
>   toward writing code for its forthcoming chip last year (see “IBM
>   Scientists Show Blueprints for Brainlike Computing”), even the best
>   programmers find learning to work with the chip bruising, says Modha:
>   “It’s almost always a frustrating experience.” His team is working to
>   create a library of ready-made blocks of code to make the process
>   easier.

Which brings me to the question, can everyday computing tasks be broken down into ones solvable by a neural network (theoretically and/or practically)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the task. 
There are plenty of tasks, for which John von Neumann computers are good enough. For example calculate precise  values of functions in some range, or for example apply some filter at image, or store text into db and read it from it or store prices of some products etc. This is not area where NN are needed. Of course it is possible theoretically to train NN to choose where and how to save data. Or to train it to accountancy. But for cases where big array of data need to be analyzed, and current methods doesn't feet  NN can be option to consider. Or speech recognition, or buying some pictures which will become masterpieces in the future can be done with NN.

Comment: Practically, all the things that humans do are already solved by neural networks : our brain.
So yes.